# Anyway to disable minification (make line breaks) in the source view of CKEditor WYSIWYG

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

My question is different from one I've seen answered quite a bit here and elsewhere. My line breaks are showing up in WYSIWYG and the rendered content just fine. However, I was wondering if there is a way to make CKEditor/WYSIWYG preserve line breaks when I view the code as well. I sometimes need to edit code in the HTML, and it's a mild inconvenience to have to sift through minified code to find stuff.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit WYSIWYG profile that uses CKEditor and in `"Cleanup and output"` settings check `"Apply simple source formatting".` (screenshots below for visuals)

---

[image]

---

[image]